# Pass move_lines into stock.picking from another model - Odoo v8

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo-8, odoo

I have this method:

```
@api.multi
def create_printy(self):
    copy_record = self.env['stock.picking'] 
    for record in self:

        order_lines = []
        for rec in record.order_lines:
            order_lines.append(
            (0,0,
            {
                'product_id': rec.isbn.id,
                'product_qty': rec.qty,
                }
            ))
        sp_types = self.env['stock.picking.type'].search([
        ('code', '=', 'outgoing')
        ])
        if len(sp_types) > 0:
            copy_record.create({
                'origin': record.name,
                'picking_type_id': sp_types[0].id,
                'move_lines': order_lines, 
                'move_type': 'direct',
                'priority': '1',
                'company_id': record.company_id.id,
            })
```

I'm trying to create a `stock.picking` from another model.

But, with this method, I have problems for `move_lines` which on `stock.picking` is related to `stock.move`.

Right now, it throws me this:

```
        Integrity Error

The operation cannot be completed, probably due to the following:
- deletion: you may be trying to delete a record while other records still reference it
- creation/update: a mandatory field is not correctly set

[object with reference: Product Unit of Measure - product.uom]
```

I know there are a few `stock.move` required fields which aren't present in my `order_lines` field.

So, my question is, how can I pass for example `product.uom` or `date_expected` which are required from my model?

Is there some similar way as it is done with `picking_type_id` in my example. for `One2many` field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take a look of what happens when you do not fill these fields in the interface (and look what they get by default). For example, in `stock.move` Odoo takes the `product_uom` from `product_id` field (through an `onchange` method). And the `date_expected` is filled in by default with the current date. So:

```
@api.multi
def create_printy(self):
    copy_record = self.env['stock.picking'] 
    for record in self:
        order_lines = []
        for rec in record.order_lines:
            order_lines.append(
            (0,0,
            {
                'product_id': rec.isbn.id,
                'product_uom': rec.isbn.uom_id.id,
                'date_expected': time.strftime(DEFAULT_SERVER_DATETIME_FORMAT),
                'product_qty': rec.qty,
                }
            ))
        sp_types = self.env['stock.picking.type'].search([
        ('code', '=', 'outgoing')
        ])
        if len(sp_types) > 0:
            copy_record.create({
                'origin': record.name,
                'picking_type_id': sp_types[0].id,
                'move_lines': order_lines, 
                'move_type': 'direct',
                'priority': '1',
                'company_id': record.company_id.id,
            })
```

For `date_expected` you will have to import in your *.py* file (out of your classes) the following:

```
import time
from openerp.tools import DEFAULT_SERVER_DATETIME_FORMAT
```

Comment: Thank You so much, Do You know in case of company_id which is required how can I pass that?

Comment: I've tried some things for company, but I'm not sure, cannot pass it, I can open a new question if needed

Comment: Oh You put that too, sorry didn't notice, gonna try, Thank You